# How to take a specific part of a line in a file using shell commands?

Tags: linux, file, bash, tail

I would like to take a specific part of the  last line of a file. say the values between "cursor position" 9 and 22? to take the last line I know I should use tail -1 but and the second part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think GNU cut can get you there.  For example:

```
cut -c 9-22
```

Or, in total:

```
tail -1 file | cut -c 9-22
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [cut](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) command.

```
$ echo "hello how are you doing" | cut -c 9-22
w are you doin
```